# recursive DataFrame query

Tags: python, dataframe, index-error

I'm writing small program to utilize data from API endpoint. As I need to solve typical problem of parent-child recursive relation I wrote function as below:

```
def get_client_path(client_id, _df: pd.DataFrame):
client_full_path = str(client_id)
current_id = client_id
while True:
    parent_record = _df.loc[_df['id'] == current_id]
    if math.isnan(parent_record['data.parentClient'].iloc[0]):
        break
    parent_id = int(parent_record['data.parentClient'].iloc[0])
    current_id = parent_id
    ic(current_id)
    client_full_path = f"{parent_id} - " + client_full_path
```

What drives me crazy is that the code throws an error: *line 1686, in _validate_integer
raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")* in line `math.isnan(parent_record['data.parentClient'].iloc[0]):`

Strange thing is that the value of `parent_record['data.parentClient'].iloc[0]` can be printed out without any errors and shows proper value. It's 64bit float.

Why I need that line? Because API endpoint returns "null" in case no parent is available.

What am I missing here?

Comment: show what `ic` does, and an example of `_df`

Comment: ic is just IceCream lib. Sorry for not pointing it out. And to _df it's dataframe that contains following columns: [id, type, data.parentClient, data.hierarchyLevel, ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is typical of `.iloc` when you are trying to slice a dataframe at a point it doesn't exist.

It's not 100% clear from your post what the cause of the error might be, but as you're slicing at the 0th index, it's likely that `parent_record['data.parentClient']` returns an empty dataframe under certain conditions.

Comment: Yeah, that "certain conditions"... ;) I can print the `parent_record['data.parentClient']` variable and got data. I checked its type - it's Series.
```ic| type(parent_record['data.parentClient']): <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
ic| parent_record['data.parentClient'].iloc[0]: 1085.0```
but the error still persist in run.

Comment: If I comment out some lines I found that the same line (ic) can the same time display value and throw exception...

Comment: I found that in this case data.parentClient pointed to... not existing record. Trying to get non-existent record returned empty dataframe. I didn't expect that, as the data are taken from database - i was pretty sure that there are some constraints protecting against such mistakes, but apparently there is no such protection. The error was thrown in second iteration and the console output order was bit misleading.